# How Test LogoutEventStream

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I am creating a functionality to count the number of minutes that a user is connected. For this I use the LogoutEventStream in a trigger. The problem is that I don't know how to test it. I already tried using:

```
Test.startTest();
EventBus.publish(new LogoutEventStream());
Test.stopTest();
```

But this returns the following error:

> System.TypeException: DML operation INSERT not allowed on
>   LogoutEventStream

Also, using this code as I specify which user will execute it?

I hope someone can give me some answer, thank you.